# iOS. Navigation controller toolbar - customize example

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm newbie with Xcode, I'm learning it and trying to make my app. 
Now I would like to put Navigation Bar func at the bottom of the screen with some customize.
I turn on "Shows Toolbar" at Navigation Controller and put my button there, but I cannot customize it.
Everything that I found about customizing Navigation Bar at the top of the screen or about customizing TabBar when people are talking about bottom of the screen.
Please, can you give me a code examples to build something like this at the bottom of the screen:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1338320/nav.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This could be a `tabBar` as well. Easily customisable.

Comment: Yep, and I've done it with TabBar. But now I understand that it doesn't fit for me because I need Navigation Bar behavior.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you have to create a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and then add subviews with your custom drawing buttons and stuff. There are a lot of examples in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to customize (button or bar) but when there is a bar at the bottom of the screen that is not a tab bar it is a tool bar not a navigation bar. The two are related but they each have their own class. Tool bars use [`UIToolBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) not `UINavigationBar`. The tool bar is independent of the navigation controller and the two work together well. For any views that don't want a tool bar just set it to hidden in `-viewDidAppear:` (you will need to un hide it in views that use it).

Comment: Thanks man! I was a little confused because the options "Shows Toolbar" at Navigation Controller. When I realized that it's an own class I found very good samples: http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitoolbar-on-a-uitableviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

dimimpou is right. You can accomplish this by using a [UITabBarViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and one [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for "ADD ONE" and "MY STATS".
If you get lost in references(I sometimes get lost too), I may provide a simple example.

Note that if the interface provided by UIKit doesn't meet your need you can:

1. Use category over UITabBar or UITabBarItem.
2. If 1. doesn't work sadly you'll have create your own view controller which is simulate UITabBarViewController(requires some time, but it's worth)

Edit:
You can use a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this. The way I understand it, you want this "Toolbar" to show from a button in the navigation bar. Just put a tab bar with what you need and make it show when the user presses the button on the navigation bar. on this buttons action put this code: self.tabBar.hidden = NO; and on the storyboard uncheck the bar visibility option. Hope it helps!